# Does NordPass Make the Same Error SpiderOak Stopped Making in 2017?

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge

According to a Reddit post I am participating in, SpiderOak “repented” of its incorrect usage of the term “zero knowledge” in 2017, as shown here:

https://medium.com/@SpiderOak/why-we-will-no-longer-use-the-phrase-zero-knowledge-to-describe-our-software-ddef2593a489

NordPass has yet to walk back its claim to a zero knowledge architecture:

https://nordpass.com/features/zero-knowledge-architecture/#

Is it technically wrong to claim that “no knowledge” is the same as “zero knowledge” as SpiderOak previously did? If so, why?

Comment: Reddit comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptography/comments/10nc1np/zeroknowledge_encryption_vs_endtoend_encryption/j68q3qp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&context=3

Comment: **Marketing texts** attempt to find short and well memorable definitions for important product features. That's why the wording "zero-knowledge" is understandable in the cases mentioned in the OP. But despite the product features have nothing to do with zero-knowledge proofs, discussion of **marketing texts** is off-topic on Crypto SE. I suggest to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cryptography outlined on the [NordPass page](https://nordpass.com/features/zero-knowledge-architecture) is not using *zero-knowledge* as that's understood in a cryptographic context, which is (per the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), [chapter 10](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap10.pdf#page=23))

> a *zero-knowledge protocol* allows a *proof* of the truth of an assertion, while conveying no information whatsoever about the assertion itself other than its actual truth.

Instead, NordPass uses *zero-knowledge architecture* (or *zero-knowledge encryption*, *zero-knowledge cloud storage*) to mean they do not hold the encryption key to the user data they store (including password vault). They describe a system with a master password, turned into a key for encryption with XChaCha20, by [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) using [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2). All this is symmetric cryptography, entirely unrelated to *zero-knowledge* as considered in the first paragraph and quote.

At least I do not see them using *zero knowledge* to qualify one of their *protocol*, or a *proof* made of something in their system.

Comment: This article may show the results of widespread ignorance spreading ever wider: https://www.howtogeek.com/811527/what-is-zero-knowledge-encryption/

Comment: @brethvoice: the above article indeed makes several errors: it talks of "zero-knowledge encryption" as if this marketing term was standard in cryptography; AES-256 is said to be a protocol; and while it acknowledges that "Zero-knowledge encryption and zero-knowledge proof are different concepts", it twice states ZK proof is used for password verification in zero-knowledge encryption, which AFAIK is not even attempted in NordPass.